# iOS8 Today Widget sometimes won't load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8-today-widget

I have an issue where my Today widget sometimes won't load. It just shows a snapshot of it's previous state. Sometimes it'll start working on it's own as well. I don't think it's crashing as I don't see any crash data in the device log, nor is it triggering a Crashlytics report. It seems to be random as well. It won't work no matter how many times I swipe down to reload it, or if I remove and re-add it to the Today menu. Doesn't seem to matter. Then it might just start working by itself hours later. I haven't been able to catch this while attached to xCode. It always seems to happen "in the wild" while using my device. In fact if it's in a state where it's not working, as soon as I attach my device and build and run,  it starts working again.

How does one go about diagnosing this problem? This is literally the only thing stopping me from submitting this app.

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.
    CLS_LOG(@"widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler");
    [RemindersManager sharedRemindersManager];
    [REMINDERS_MANAGER refreshData];
    _remindersArray = [REMINDERS_MANAGER storedReminders];
    _armedRemindersArray = [REMINDERS_MANAGER armedReminders];
    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData
    [_userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"WidgetFirstRunComplete"];
    [_userDefaults synchronize];

    CLS_LOG(@"Widget first run status %d", [_userDefaults boolForKey:@"WidgetFirstRunComplete"]);

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: could you post the code of `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:`?

Comment: I edited my question to include the code.

Comment: I also encountered this problem. How did you solve finally?